# Memory Access Times

Tags: speed, memory-timings

Apologies if this isn't the right place to ask but I'm pretty stuck at this point. I've been searching all day and no one seems to have the information that I need.

What I'm looking for are the average access speeds for a few different kinds of memory:

- CPU Registers
- CPU Caches
- Primary Memories (RAM)
- Flash Memories
- Hard disks (which I think are ~9ms)
- DVDs

All I've been able to find thus far are transfer rates, not access times. Ideally if someone could just point me in the right direction, like a link to wiki that I've obviously missed that would be awesome :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, RAM-type memory this is pretty easy, as they tend to run on standard bus speeds. But DVDs/Flash/Hard Drives will be all over the place - they are highly dependant on the individual device - HDD's for example can have an average seek time of between about 3 and 15ms (from max performance server drives to impact-resistant mobile drives), and an average latency of between 2 and 6ms (depending of rotational speed). So a HDD could have an average access time anywhere between ~5 and 21ms.

Comment: Indeed, but as long as I can get a ball park I'm not that worried :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out so far

- DRAM     -    60 ns (35ns cycle time and 25ns latency time).
- SDRAM    -    10 ns.

[image]

Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random_access_memory)

Comment: Nice, I can't believed I missed this, wiki is more or less the only place I've found useful so far. Thanks :)